# HTTPClient gives 404 without www for a url

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

I am using apache HTTPClient 4.2. I used this below code to get the HTTP status code. It gives me `404`.

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpUriRequest method = new HttpGet("http://michaelkimsal.com/blog/hosted-solr-or-lucene-service/comment-page-1/#comment-604253");
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(method,context);
            int status = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("The status is:"+status);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But if Change the url to this(I have added www to url), `http://www.michaelkimsal.com/blog/hosted-solr-or-lucene-service/comment-page-1/#comment-604253` it gives me `200`. What may be the reason for this behavior? Please some one help come out of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://michaelkimsal.com is not valid domain in your case, browser is intelligent in some case that automatically handle such case, you should use proper domain with www.

Edit
please check [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/110936/whats-the-difference-between-domainname-com-and-www-domainname-com) link of serverault and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name)

It works for google because it has done dns resolution setup for that. You can also setup aliases

Comment: Thanks. But it works for google.com and many others. you said its not a valid domain name. I am new and I would really like to know about how its not a valid domain name.